# Prevent git push against remote repository when username of pusher is not configured

Tags: git

I want to prevent users from pushing to my repository when their usernames aren't set correctly. In practice I'd like this:

```
foreach commit in pushed_stuff:
   if not commit.username in some_list:
       reject push
```

The hook `pre-receive` seems appropriate but how do I extract the username from each commit object that is received? `update` seems to get the object names but from my understanding that happens when it's already in my repository (just before the ref has moved).

EDIT: This isn't meant to be some security mechanism to only allow certain people to push to me. I trust everyone, but sometimes people mess up and forget to configure their `.gitconfig`.

UPDATE: I had a problem with VonC's suggestion. When using pre-receive, if someone pushes a new branch the `<old-value>` is "000000000". So if he had made several commits to that new branch and he tries to push it, doing git rev-list ... $new only gives me one commit. But maybe other commits before it have had a bad username that I want to reject. I couldn't find a way to tell git to give me all the new commits. When the branch already exists doing git rev-list ... $old..$new does the job.

Comment: if you have a functioning hook script, you can also post here as an additional answer. I'm sure it will be useful for a lot of other Git repo administrators out there ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is addressed a bit in "[Git/gitosis: How to check validity of user name and email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824990/git-gitosis-how-to-check-validity-of-user-name-and-email)".

Now, the referenced SO question is about a security mechanism (which you don't want), but :

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%ae $new
```

can help in a [`pre-receive` hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive), as suggested by [Bombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43582/bombe) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824990/git-gitosis-how-to-check-validity-of-user-name-and-email/825119#825119).
`%an` or `%aN` might be more adapted to your case here.

> This hook executes once for the receive operation. It takes no arguments, but for each ref to be updated it receives on standard input a line of the format:

```
<old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
```

> where:
>
> - `<old-value>` is the old object name stored in the ref,
> - `<new-value>` is the new object name to be stored in the ref and
> - `<ref-name>` is the full name of the ref.
>
> When creating a new ref, `<old-value>` is 40 0.

Comment: I had one problem with this. If someone pushes a new branch the <old-value> is "000000000". So if he had made several commits to that new branch and he tries to push it, doing `git rev-list ... $new` only gives me one commit. But maybe other commits before it have a bad username that I want to reject. I couldn't find a way to tell git to give me all the new commits. When the branch already exists doing `git rev-list ... $old..$new` does the job.