# Is there a way to force people use git-flow by restricting direct commits to the master branch or something similar?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

I was wondering if there is any way to force people to use git-flow and let them push only if they are working under the git-flow patter? just to avoid developers to push directly to the master branch. I am using bitbucket (if it helps).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable push to specific branches on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520618/disable-push-to-specific-branches-on-github)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant this question seems to be about BitBucket specifically, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @jpganz18 it would be a different question, depending on whether you want the answer for BitBucket or for a self-hosted git server: an answer that would be valid for a self-hosted git most likely wouldn't help a BitBacket user at all.

Comment: I don't use bitbucket but would this https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/ resolve your issue?

Comment: @RyanMacG that seemed to be a perfectly good answer (upvoted). Don't understand why you switched it to a comment instead

Comment: I was told link only answers are frowned upon so I changed it since I had no real information to add from myself