# Set up access control in git (in our own Git server)

Tags: git, acl

Is there a way that I can deny certain users from pushing into master branch on my staging/production server ? I came across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520618/disable-push-to-specific-branches-on-github) posted two years ago, but I wonder if somebody can shed more light on this matter

**EDIT**

We are not hosting our Git projects on an external dedicated hosting sites like github

Comment: are you using github as well?

Comment: What are you using as your Git server? Github or GitLab or Stash or Gitolite? As far as I remember, Github, GitLab and Stash had the feature to prevent force pushes. This is a question you have to ask the sales/technical teams of the Git servers. Not stackoverflow.

Comment: We use our own git server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the server, then you can add a Git repo hosting service which includes some ACL feature.

- [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html)
- [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/features/) (which [can protect a branch](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html), preventing developers to push to master)

([Gogs](https://gogs.io/) does [not have yet that feature](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/776#issuecomment-238006864))

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using as your Git server: Github or GitLab or Stash or Gitolite? As far as I remember, [Github force push](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/admin/articles/blocking-force-pushes-to-a-repository/), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/), [gitolite force push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980750/gitolite-permissions-on-branches) and [Stash force push](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6714088) features exist. You will find definitive answers to this question on the respective servers websites. All of them have explained it.

If you have further doubts, write to their sales/technical teams. They have dedicated people who will answer your queries in detail.

Comment: Please see the edit, we collaborate using our own dedicated git server